# Github Permission denied pubkey when it used to work fine

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to push to github (using eclipse) as well as a `git push origin master` and using the github app.

However, as the title says I am getting a permission denied pubkey even though everything was working about a week ago.  Also ssh-add -l shows the correct key, and github.com has the correct key added.

I have no idea what happened because it was just working fine!

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You will need to update your question with more details:  your operating system, the exact error message you're getting, output of `git remote show origin`, your `.git/config` file, output of `ssh-add -l`, and the versions of the relevant programs.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the issue persists: there are some issue in the [GitHub status history](https://status.github.com/messages) currently:

> Yesterday, July 09, 2013
>
> 23:05 UTC All services are responsive and we are continuing to monitor the situation closely to ensure it remains stable.
> 22:55 UTC Gist, API, and download services are back online. Service Hook processing remains unavailable.
> 22:21 UTC We are currently investigating connectivity issues accessing Gist, the API, and archive downloads

So it could be a simple side effect.

If not, check if a simple `ssh git@github.com` still work, and try cloning again the repo to see (again) if the issue persists.

Comment: ssh git@github.com gives `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0` but ssh -T works fine.  I am able to commit in the github app then sync and changes get uploaded, however when I try in terminal or eclipse, I cannot push.  I guess I can just make do with using the github app.